# Trying use jquery to add a "Mailto" to a link tag which is compatible with all browsersr all browsers

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi i am attempting to ad a href to a `<a>` tag, so that when the user clicks on the image it opens an email.

The label text updates nicely, but the anchor href does not appear to work with the jquery for adding said href to the  tag

here is the asp:

```
<a class="hrefEditMailTo"><img src="Images/MailTo24x20.png" class="imgEditMailTo darkenOnHover" alt="Click to email me" /></a>
    <asp:Label ID="lblIDMailToImage" CssClass="lblMailToImage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
 //Dynamically change the labels text next to the email icon on the popup.
                var imgLabelText = "Send an email to requester/contact (" + strRequestersemail +")"
                if (strRequestersemail == "") {
                    imgLabelText = "Send email to a contact"
                    $('.hrefEditMailTo').prop('href', "mailto:" + strRequestersemail + "?Subject=There%20has%20been%20a%20comment%20added%20to%20your%20order%20" + strPWNum + "");

                };
                $("#<%=lblIDMailToImage.ClientID%>").text(imgLabelText);
```

Comment: can you please add the generated html ? It will helps !

Comment: i solved it, the strRequesterEmail was not = to "" so it was a noob mistake on my behalf.